# How do I provide a local download link to files denied by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, download, localhost

Users who log in to an admin area of a website need to be able to download files that have been previously uploaded by other admins.  Public access to these files is not allowed.

The files are held in a directory called uploaded-files and there is a .htaccess in that folder:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(pdf|doc|docx|ods|xls|xlsx|ppt)$">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
</FilesMatch>
```

That seems to work ok.. The public can't link to the files.  The trouble is that the logged in admins can't link to them either because:

```
<a href"uploaded-files/abc.pdf">download</a>
```

gives a 403 forbidden when clicked.  So it seems php/html files on the server can't access the files either.

What am I doing wrong?  Surely there is an easy way to allow people on the server to download files via a link but still deny access to public?

I've tried keeping the files outside the public_html but I can't provide a link to that location either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should keep these files outside your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.
2. Download links should be via a PHP file e.g. **`<a href"http://domain.com/download-files.php?file=abc.pdf">download abc.pdf</a>`**
3. php code can check for auth part and allowed host etc. If all validations pass then return content of PDF with proper CONTENT type to the browser.

Comment: Thanks, and download.pdp can access files outside document root because it uses readfile instead of <a href etc - is that right?